# Fetch JSON data from an array within an array

Tags: json

Lets say I have a URL that brings out this JSON object.

How do I fetch `Albertson`?

```
{
  "ancestor" : [
    {
      "father" : [
         {
           "long_name" : "Albertson",
           "short_name" : "Roger",
           "types" : [ "surname" ]
         }
       ]
     }
  ],
}
```

Is it `ancestor[0][0].long_name`?

Comment: `obj.ancestor[0].father[0].long_name`

Comment: "Is it ...?" Did you try?

Comment: I am working with PHP

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the data using

```
object.ancestor[0].father[0].long_name
```

You can also refer: http://www.json.com/#object-with-nested-array-and-object

Comment: So how can i get the country from this json ?

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA

Comment: Just try this you will get the `country` from json data `object.results[0].address_components[5].types[0]`